# mongodb log file returning continuous lines of flushed journal instances

Tags: mongodb, startup

Why is it that when I type 'mongod -f \pluralsight\mongod.conf' (path of my conf file) in terminal, I get the following flush spam in my log file? :

[image]

Is this normal?

Here is my configuration file in case you need it.

[image]

I recently installed MongoDB and I just don't want a file that is logging that my storage is being flushed, seems like poor data management. I'm not sure what is available to me to address this, or if this is normal and permissible, or if maybe there's something I'm doing wrong when I started this project.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it's because in my mongod.conf file I had the verbose property set to  "verbose=vvvvvv". I set it to "verbose=vvv" so it shows less info on logged.